# Using a Hash as a reference is deprecated - Perl

Tags: perl, hash, reference, deprecated

I am trying to install scmbug on my windows platform. 
I am getting Hash as a reference error in the below method. see the "HERE" annotation to see where it is happening.

Should i replace every %mail with $mail in it.

I tried this but got other errors. Saying

Global symbol "$mail" requires explicit package name

how to get this fixed ?

```
sub mail_notification_send_mail {
   my $self = shift;
   my ($request, $subject, $message, $mailing_list) = ( @_ );
   my %mail;

   # Set values. This permits users to override the default behavior
   # of Mail::Sendmail
   %mail = \%{ $request->{ policies }->{ mail_notification }->{ mail_settings } };
   %mail->{ 'X-Mailer' } = "Mail::Sendmail version $Mail::Sendmail::VERSION";  HERE
   %mail->{ Subject } = $subject; HERE
   %mail->{ Message } = $message; HERE

   #
   # Since we just reset %mail to values, we haven't really picked up
   # the To,From,Reply-To that were computed. We do this next
   #

   # Don't blindly ignore the To list that was computed
   my $mailing_list_to = $self->emails_to_csv( $mailing_list->{ To } );
   %mail->{ To } = $mailing_list_to; HERE

   # Don't blindly ignore the From list that was computed
   my $mailing_list_from = $self->emails_to_csv( $mailing_list->{ From } );
   %mail->{ From } = $mailing_list_from; HERE

   # Don't blindly ignore the 'Reply-To' list that was computed
   my $mailing_list_replyto = $self->emails_to_csv( $mailing_list->{ 'Reply-To' } );
   %mail->{ 'Reply-To' } = $mailing_list_replyto; HERE


   if ( !sendmail(%mail) ) {
   my $msg = "Sending mail on " . $request->{ name } .
       " failed. Log error was:\n" . $Mail::Sendmail::error . "\n";
   $request->add_result(1, $msg);
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation: [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

You have a hashref, but you are using a hash's sigil. Replace all `%mail` with `$mail`.

You have:

```
%mail = \%{ $request->{ policies }->{ mail_notification }->{ mail_settings } };
```

The `\%` tells perl to dereference the hash and return a hashref, but you are assigning it to a hash. I'd bet you get a warning there too. The line should be:

```
$mail = $request->{ policies }->{ mail_notification }->{ mail_settings }; ## change all `%mail` to `$mail`
```

or

```
%mail = %{ $request->{ policies }->{ mail_notification }->{ mail_settings } }; ## change all `%mail->{something}` to `$mail{something}`.
```

Comment: Your first line should be my %hash I think

Comment: @Disco3, I already edited it and completely changed my answer. I didn't notice that he was assigning a hashref into a hash. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$mail->{ ... }` in order to de-reference. But in your case you have a hash `%mail` instead of a reference, so the proper way to access its members is without the dereferencing operator `->`. A simply `$mail{...}` will suffice.

Comment: The `%mail` hash is being assigned a hashref, so the OP will need to do a little more work than just changing how it is accessed.

Comment: True. Removing the `\` in `%mail = \%{...` would suffice, like the accepted answer stated.